# How to get the list of roles which could access an object in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am looking to `audit the access for our datasets in S3` . Since the access controls are at iam policies , S3 bucket policies and access control list .. getting a list of roles which could potentially access a dataset in S3 is really hard to identify manually.

Are there any libraries or code to accomplish the same

Comment: I think there is no tool that would provide a complete picture for your. But probably you could find something just for some limited analysis, -only bucket policies, only IAM user policies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the roles, bucket and IAM policies, extract the policy statements, and search for an `s3:` string match in the results.